# A value of type 'List<Object?>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'

Tags: database, flutter, list

it says   "  A value of type 'List<Object?>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'" how can i resolve it

```
Future markSetss() async {
    
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('stations')
    .where('norequest', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 5)
    .get();

List<Map<String, dynamic>> results =
    querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right, it just needs a type cast on the `data()` like this:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> results =
querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>).toList();
```